# Httpclient continuous multipart stream

Tags: c#, stream, httpclient, multipart

I totally hit my limit here:

I am working with an API that offers me this:

> For a running event, the video images can be received in the form of a
>   continuous multipart stream. The stream ends as soon as the event
>   finishes.

Would would I capture this?

I started coding something like this:

```
System.Net.WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
```

which works like a charm, as long as there is only 1 response.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, you'll need to know how many bytes to read, and check for end of logical response inside the stream.